# How to get difference in hours from 2 dates in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, service

Can anyone help me please with a problem.I have added into a list some data like that.

```
$scope.cars=[{
    Plate:"aa55aa",
    Color:"green",
    Entrance:new date ()
}]
```

I want to make a factory service  in AngularJS that calculate the hours that the car spent in the parking area but when i wrote in the service factory the difference between entrance.getHours and the date from now it said to me that the date is undefined.
Can anyone help me please? It is about an example from the book Angular The Essentials.

Comment: Are you doing `new date()` or `new Date()`? Capitalization matters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the car total hours/spent in the parking lot you can use **momentjs** to calculate the time you need a **start date** and **end date**.

```
var start  = "11/08/2017 15:00:00";
var end = "11/08/2017 14:20:30";

var spent = moment.utc(moment(start,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss").diff(moment(end,"DD/MM/YYYY HH:mm:ss"))).format("HH:mm:ss");

console.log(spent);
```

// outputs: "00:39:30"

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to capitalize the Date object in `new Date()`

```
$scope.cars = [{
    Plate:"aa55aa",
    Color:"green",
    Entrance:new Date()
}];
```